# JSF, Icefaces, Portlets and Requestparameter

Tags: java, jsf, portlet, icefaces

I'm trying ton include some JSF into my webapp. For the components lib I've choosed ICEFaces, now I'm facing a problem:

ICEFaces doesn't trigger the processAction method which is required to get requestparameters. In my other "normal" portlets I can do - in JBoss Portal - e.g.

```
 /portal/dashboard/hellpPortlet_Window?action=1&query=Works
```

With Icefaces I cannot do that

```
/portal/dashboard/jsfPortlet_Windows?query=Works
```

is always nulll.

I'm already accessing the Externalcontext in my managed-bean (scope request). Does anyone knows an other approach to get the request params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used ICEFaces, and regret it, if you stil didn't do too much, for web UI, I'd go with something else. 
GWT, EXT-JS (the LGPL Branch), Flex or JQuery, but ICEFaces still causes nightmares to some of our developers...

Comment: Well I refused it and replaced it with Richfaces with the JBoss Portlet Bridge - If someone can point me the way to get use of the "portlet bridge request scope", I'll be happy

Comment: Please add it as an answer to your own question, and approve it as the chosen answer, seems better than mine ;)